# How do I scale a DIV to full width?

Tags: html, css, width, scaling

I'd like to set a DIV to 100% of the page width rather than 100% of the window width.

So, if my content is wider than the browser window, I want the DIV to still scale to the full width rather than ending in the middle of the page as it does with `width: 100%`.

Nesting it into a DIV with `width: 200%; overflow: visible;` basically works, but has the side effect that you can scroll along all the 200%. And even then, if the content exceeds double the window width, the div will end in mid-air.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nm64V/ (please note that the 3000px wide content is just an example, in my project I don't know how wide the content will be and when it will exceed the window width)

How do I achieve the descripted behavior?

Comment: Does your HTML and BODY styles have a width set to 100% as well?
Is this specific DIV nested into another tag (other than the BODY tag I mean)? You might be forgetting the 'display: ...' and 'position: ...' properties to get your DIV working correctly.

Comment: It is nested in an overall wrapper DIV which has got `margin: 0` and nothing else. The next element above this wrapper is BODY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe what you want to do is possible like that. You'll probably need to give a more concrete example of what you want to achieve.

Until then I give one guess that may work: Give the surrounding element (`<body>` may work, otherwise add one) `display: table-cell`, since table cells stretch to fit their contents. If you need to support older browsers that don't support `display: table-cell`, try adding a single celled table around the contents instead.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nm64V/2/

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you can solve this issue by wrapping all your content in a div set to the size of the content. Using your example:

```
<div style="margin: 0">
    <div style="width: 3000px;">
        <div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
        <div>... Your long content goes here ...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, whatever width you set the container div to (say, 1500px), both the inner div (with the red border) and your content will be that width, even if it stretches beyond the browser window.

In the case that you don't know what size the container div will be, take out the 'style="width: 3000px;"' line, and it will still work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nm64V/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably provide an example of what you're trying to do precisely. As a DIV is a block element, it should always take all the width available, unless it's empty or floated.

Is the "content" you're talking about inside that said DIV or somewhere else in the page?

Comment: Added an example case to my question.